# Issue with custom loss function including parameters in keras autoencoder

Tags: keras, loss-function, autoencoder

I am writing an **Autoencoder** that tries to find parameters for 3D Meshes. For example, how bent an object is. I input the Mesh vertices but would like to include the **true parameters** versus the Autoencoders latent space in the loss function.
I already wrote this function after some searching around but I don't know how to index from the **current batch** to get the right parameters from the numpy array param_true.

[image: Custom loss function for Autoencoder including mesh vertices and parameters]

So basically what I would like is to get the same batch from the param_true array as the Autoencoder is using at the moment so I can calculate the loss from the right elements.

At the same time, I do not want to use the parameters as inputs.
Thanks in advance!